# Area under a never-continuous function

Tags: integration, continuity

I was thinking about the following function, infamous for being nowhere continuous:
$$f(x\in\mathbb Q)=0$$
$$f(x\notin \mathbb Q)=1$$
How would I calculate the area under this "curve" from $x=0\to1$? Can it be done?

If so, I suspect the result would be very interesting... it would tell us "what proportion of numbers are rational".

But my intuition tells me it cannot be done, because of the lack of a limit anywhere in this function.

Also, something tells me it should be zero, because when using a Riemann Sum, the input of each term will be rational as the interval is divided into rational subintervals.

Any ideas?

Comment: It depends on what type of integration you're referring to.  If you want Riemann integration, the integral is not defined.  If you want Lebesgue integration, the integral is $1$.

Comment: What is "area" to you? Whether or not this defines an area is a philosophical question. But to maths: the facts are the integral $\int_0^1f(x)\,dx$ does not exist as a Riemann integral, but as a Lebesgue integral, it exists and its value is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

The area under this curve is called its [Lebesgue integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration) and is equal to $1$, corresponding to the intuition that most numbers in the interval $[0,1]$ are actually irrationnal.

The Lebesgue integral is an extension of the Riemann integral to a wider class of functions (called "measurable functions"). In your example, $f$ is not Riemann-integrable so there is no hope to compute its integral using Riemann sums.